# how to create row dynamic and save to database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, dynamic

Hello I have a big problem. I need to add dynamic row in my timesheet and save them to my database. Here what look like my timesheet !http://cjoint.com/data/0DptGlbePgo.htm
And I need for each day able to add project client, description lieu ( location in english) and a total. for each day a button under the day for adding row. And when I press the button finish ( not show in the picture cause its only show when condition is complete) I want to add them in my database. For the moment I will show how I proceed.

Here and exemple of one of my day ( monday)

```
<!-----------------------------------LUNDI----------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Lundi</b> </br><?php echo $date2 ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    </br>
                    <input size="10" type="text" id="projlundi" name="projlundi"onkeypress="return handleEnter2(event, this, 'task');"/>

                </td>
                <td>
                    </br>

                    <input type="text" name="projdesclundi" size="30" class "desc" id ="projdesclundi"readonly />
                </td>
                <td>
                    </br>
                    <textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="taskdesclundi" id="taskdesclundi"/> </textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    </br>
                    <input type="text" name="lieu1" size="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                </br>

<!-- dꣵt section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->                    
                    <label title="Selectlundi"> <select title="Selectlundi" id="Selectlundi" name="Selectlundi">
                    <?php

                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo ' <option title="';
                            echo $row['tacName'];
                            echo '">';
                            echo $row['tacId'];
                            echo '</option>'."\n";
                         $task = array();

                            //echo '<option value="'.$row['tacName'].'">'.$row['tacId'].'</option>'."\n";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
        </label>
<!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->    
                </td>   
            <!-- calculter le temps pour le lundi -->       

                        <td>
                        </br>
                    <span id="calculTemps1">
                            <input type="number" id="input2" class="temps" name="tempsl"  max="24" min="0" value="0" />

                    </span>
                </td>   

        </tr>
```

And Here is how I insert my monday to my database

```
<?php
 session_start();
// Connect to the DB
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cruel', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

    $timId = "" ;


//lundi

if (isSet($_POST['projdesclundi']))
    {
    $usrUserName =  $_POST['usrUserName'] ;
    $lieu1 = $_POST['lieu1'] ;
    $projdesclundi = $_POST['projdesclundi'] ;
    $timDateStartOfWeek = $_POST['data'] ;
    $Selectlundi =  $_POST['Selectlundi'] ;
    $projlundi =  $_POST['projlundi'] ;
    $date2 =  $_POST['date2'] ;
    $tempsl =  $_POST['tempsl'] ;
    }   



        //---------------------------- INSERTION lundi--------------------------------------

                    // Insertion description,location tache, numero de projet
            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO projetstaches 
            (prtDescription,prtLocation,prtTaskId,prtProjetNum,prtDate,prtTime,prtTimeSheetId)
            VALUES(:projdesclundi, :lieu1 ,:Selectlundi, :projlundi, :date2, :tempsl, :timId )');
            $req->execute(array(

                'projdesclundi' => $projdesclundi,
                    'lieu1' => $lieu1,
                    'Selectlundi'=> $Selectlundi,
                    'projlundi'=> $projlundi,
                    'date2'=> $date2,
                    'tempsl'=> $tempsl,
                    'timId'=> $timId,

            ));
```

So my question with the code I've show how do I proceed I tried many thing in ajax , jquery, javascrip0t and all have fail. and create many bug. If I forget something to show my apologies I'll edit cause I have more than 15 page so you understand my post would be too long.

**EDIT THIS IS HOW I POST MY PAGE autocomplete.php to insert.php**

before my sunday ( same as monday code ) I have my

```
<form action = 'insert.php' method="post"  >
```

and at the end after saturday ( last day for my time sheet)I have this

```
<input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly" name="total" />

<input type="hidden" name="date2" value="<?php echo $date2; ?>" />

<input type="submit"  value="TerminÃ©" id="end" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="usrUserName" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />

</p>
</form>
```

Comment: it `isset` not `isSet` (better), and you need to show us how did you try to send your data from your html to the php for us to be able to help

Comment: That not change anything but I just changed it in my code. Do you have suggestion for my problem?

Comment: it is not an error, just better. I can't suggest anything, can you show how are you are trying to submit your data to php?

Comment: Yes no prob, I've edit that what you wanted to see my post action?

Comment: Use this line under your `catch` in `insert.php` `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and then submit your form, and paste your errors pls

Comment: `code
catch (Exception $e)
{
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}`
 like that? IF Yes : no error habe been show.

Comment: no like this: `catch (Exception $e) {...} $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: hmmmm and no data in your table?!

Comment: I add some data to try it

Comment: No error at all after i fill my blank input and submit to my insert.php but how to add a dynamic button ( adding) row for each day? and save them after in my database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bind_param - before execute!

```
 $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO projetstaches 
            (prtDescription,prtLocation,prtTaskId,prtProjetNum,prtDate,prtTime,prtTimeSheetId)
            VALUES(:projdesclundi, :lieu1 ,:Selectlundi, :projlundi, :date2, :tempsl, :timId )');
$req->bind_param('ssssssss',
      $usrUserName,
     $lieu1,
     $projdesclundi,
     $timDateStartOfWeek,
     $Selectlundi,
     $projlundi,
     $date2,
     $tempsl);

     $req->execute();
```

Note: the first parameter of bindparam is a string containing the types of the data that are coming next. You can always use 's' (for string). In the example above there is one 's' for each datafield.

Comment: he is passing an `array` to `execute()` that's same as binding.

Comment: I know how to add my input in my database That what I'm saying THIS PART WORKING. I'm looking something like this : http://blog.calendarscripts.info/dynamically-adding-input-form-fields-with-jquery/ Addind row dynamic and after I could save them like I save my input